# Formulario para subir un documento a mi servidor

Tags: php, mysql

estoy empezando con php y ya voy adquiriendo los conocimiento básicos, pero me acabo de dar de frente con una pared al intentar hacer un formulario con un campo para subir un documento y otro input para poner un número, y que al subir el documento, esté se renombre con el número que le he asignado en el input. Se que me falta código por poner, pero no se cómo hacerlo.

**Tengo este trozo de código en este momento**

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
              <input name="uploadedfile" type="file"/>
              <input type="number" placeholder="Nº de Albarán">
              <input type="submit" value="SUBIR Y COMPLETAR AVISO"/>
</form>
```

**Y aquí el código de la función**

```html
<?php 

function dbConnect (){
  $conn = null;
  $host = 'Localhost';
  $db =  'db_name';
  $user = 'db_user';
  $pwd =  'db_pass';
 try {
     $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pwd);

 }
 catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo '<p>Error al conectar a la base de datos</p>';
     exit;
 }
 return $conn;
 }


$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 
  echo "El archivo ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " ha sido subido";
} 
 else{
 echo "Ha ocurrido un error";
}
 ?>
```

Comment: ¿Estás teniendo algún error, o simplemente ese código no hace nada? Hay muchas cosas que pueden estar ocurriendo, por lo que sería útil que comentes dónde se encuentra tu dificultad.

Comment: si perdona, el archivo lo consigo subir, lo que no consigo ni se hacer es que cuando suba el archivo, se renombre con el Nº que doy en el input

Comment: Tendrías que pasar el número del input al código PHP, recuperarlo allí e incorporarlo en la variable `$target_path`.  La mejor manera de hacer eso sería mediante una petición Ajax.

Comment: No se muy bien como hacer eso, estoy empezando en php y me cuesta un poco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero arreglas tu input que tienes, debes colocarle **"nombre"** y siempre debes colocarle un **"id"** ya que te facilitará muchos procesos realizados con javascript y php. Sabiendo esto cambias tu input:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Nº de Albarán">
```

Por:

```
<input id="number" name="number" type="number" placeholder="Nº de Albarán">
```

De manera que tu html quedará de la siguiente forma (he colocado **"name"** e **"id"** a cada elemento recuerda hacer esto siempre para los `<form>` y los `<input>`):

```
<form id="carga_archivo" name="carga_archivo" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
              <input id="uploadedfile" name="uploadedfile" type="file"/>
              <input id="number" name="number" type="number" placeholder="Nº de Albarán">
              <input id="enviar" name="enviar" type="submit" value="SUBIR Y COMPLETAR AVISO"/>
</form>
```

Obtienes el número por post:

```
$nombre_archivo=$_POST['number'];
```

Debes saber que **formato** estas manejando en los archivos (que archivos vas a recibir unicamente). Si solo recibirás **".txt"** por ejemplo debes modificar el nombre de archivo como:

```
$nombre_archivo= $_POST['number'].'txt';
```

Si es **pdf** entonces:

```
$nombre_archivo= $_POST['number'].'pdf';
```

Si no te decides por un formato en particular pues obtienes el tipo de formato de **$_FILES**. Así:

```
$tipo_archivo = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'];

$tipo_archivo = explode("/", $tipo_archivo);
$tipo_archivo= '.'.$tipo_archivo[1];

$nombre_archivo= $_POST['number'].$tipo_archivo;
```

Esta línea de código que tienes no iría ya:

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```

Sino irían estas:

```
$target_path = "uploads/";
$nombre_archivo= $_POST['number'].'pdf'; // según si es pdf o txt u otro
$target_path = $target_path.$nombre_archivo;
```

De esa forma si tu input "number" envia el valor "0023" por ejemplo, tomando en cuenta tu ruta entonces quedaría así:

```
$target_path = 'uploads/0023.pdf';
```

y ya cuando lo cargues tendra el nombre que necesitas. Te coloco tu código completo de php pero con las correcciones ya realizadas:

```
 <?php 

    function dbConnect (){
        $conn = null;
        $host = 'Localhost';
        $db =   'db_name';
        $user = 'db_user';
        $pwd =  'db_pass';
        try {
            $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pwd);

        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p>Error al conectar a la base de datos</p>';
            exit;
        }
        return $conn;
     }


    $target_path = "uploads/";
    $nombre_archivo= $_POST['number'].'pdf'; // recuerda cambiar esto por el 
                                             //formato de archivo que 
                                             // quieras... 'jpg', 'txt', etc
    $target_path = $target_path.$nombre_archivo;

     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 
        echo "El archivo ".$nombre_archivo. " ha sido subido";
    } 
     else{
        echo "Ha ocurrido un error";
    }
     ?>
```

Eso es todo. Un Saludo

Comment: de las mejores respuestas que me han dado en esta plataforma, sin duda. Me funciona perfectamente, sólo me queda una duda. No tengo preferencias respecto a la extensión del archivo, por lo que no le he puesto la extensión 'pdf' 'jpg' ...etc pero a la hora de subir el archivo, aparece sin extensión, no se como poner para poner la extensión original del archivo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apreciación! Ya edite mi respuesta para que veas como se hace con un formato de archivo aleatorio, espero te sirva también. Un Saludo

Comment: Añadí las dos lineas nuevas que me comentaste pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar. En esta linea $tipo_archivo = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type']; cambiando "type" por jpg o pdf si funciona, pero no me cambia la extensión

Comment: necesito que cuando yo suba un archivo como por ejemplo (imagen.png) se guarde tal cual (imagen.png). ahora me lo guarda así (imagenpng). Necesito que al descargarme ese archivo subido al servidor, conserve la extensión con la que se subió

Comment: ya edite mi respuesta. Reemplaza donde va $tipo_archivo=$tipo_archivo[1]; por $tipo_archivo= '.'.$tipo_archivo[1]; y prueba ya debería aparecerte exactamente el nombre

Comment: Ahora si! Muchas gracias, me has ayudado mucho, gracias por la dedicacion

Comment: De nada! Me alegra que pude ayudar. Un Saludo.